# Create open 80 port for Storybook for React

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, port, storybook

Original port for my Storybook installation was port 8080 and 6006 see documentation [enter link description here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/workflows/publish-storybook), and figured to change the JSON file to point to port 80

This is the package.json file part of my Storybook installation:
[image: This is the package.json file part of my Storybook installation:]

Now I've assigned a domain name since port 80 is hosted under the public ip, the problem is after a while that port closes and we can't see the Storybook because the port is closed again. How do I configure so that the port stays open? I'm using Jelastic as a web hosting environment: https://jelastic.com/

My current configuration is as followed:

Running a VPS with Ubuntu 18.04 installed

Other dependencies:

- NPM
- Yarn
- NodeJS
- Create React App : https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html
- StoryBook for React : https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/introduction
- Chromatic : https://www.chromatic.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storybook's webserver is not meant to be exposed to the internet, it's only for local development. You can create a static build of your Storybook using `yarn build-storybook` and upload that to any hosting provider. However, since you're using Chromatic, you don't have to, because it gives you free hosting out of the box. See https://www.chromatic.com/docs/document#direct-access-to-your-storybook for details.